# Фреймворк Google Web Toolkit

Tags: gwt, веб-программирование

Почему многие не любят Google Web Toolkit? Какие приемущества и недостатки у Google Web Toolkit?

Comment: В тему http://hashcode.ru/questions/33343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Преимущества: кроссбраузерность, возсожность использовать широкий спектр средств java разработки(ide, тесты, build tools, debugger итд)
Недостатки:относительно выскокий порог входа, некоторый оверхед по ресурсам относительно js, меньшее количество библиотек и фреймворков по сравнению с js либо необходимость писать для них обертки.

Преимущество gwt будет показывать скорее в больших проектах.